# How to check a key exists in SortedListWithKey (SortedContainers )

Tags: python

I am using a SortedListWithKey and I don't know how to check if a key is already present.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedListWithKey
l = SortedListWithKey(key=lambda i: i[0])
l.add( (4, 'item1') ) 
l.add( (-12,'item2') ) 
l.add( (21,'item3') )
```

How can I check key '4' is already present?

Answer (score 0):

Use l.bisect_key_left

```
> i = l.bisect_key_left(4)
> i
1
>>> (i!=len(l) and l[i][0] == 4)
True

> i = l.bisect_key_left(34)
> i
3
> (i!=len(l) and l[i][0] == 4)
False

> i = l.bisect_key_left(21)
> i
2
> (i!=len(l) and l[i][0] == 4)
False
```